# Update a WinForms-Application automatically (async)

Tags: c#, winforms, webclient, auto-update

I am trying to write a little application and, as I am only a student, i was wondering if someone maybe could help me with with some advices / tips to achieve the following:

On start, the desired program shall call a special function. That function looks onto a remote server (most likely it will be a NAS - network attached storage - with given username + password) if there is an update available. If yes, download & install it (including a display of the current progress) and restart program afterwards.

Having done some research, I found the following code snippet, hope it helps:

```
var webClient = new WebClient();  
webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);  
webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);  
webClient.DownloadFileAsync("https://195.50.139.130:5001/FTP/KlingGastro Update/file.txt", "C:\\file.txt");
```

Please note there is a blank character between KlingGastro and Update.
Furthermore the credentials are "KlingGastro" as username, please excuse that I will not post password due to security reasons. Lets say its "myPassword".

I think downloading is not going to be that big problem, I already found this tutorial:
https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/227/how-to-download-a-webfile-with-csharp-and-show-download-progress-synchronously-and-asynchronously
Rather the cancellation of the program by itself and the restart might could be difficult?

Sorry for all potential language faults in addition, hope it was nevertheless somehow understandable.
Would be really happy for every answer and help effort.

Best regards

Comment: Is ClickOnce deployment an option?

Answer (score 0):

A call to "System.Windows.Forms.Application.Restart()" within the DownloadFileCompleted event-handler will do this for you after the update is completed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, You May Need To Clear Your Question A Bit Furthermore. If You Are Wanting Your Program To Cancel The Download Task And Then Restart The Program Again,

```
webClient.CancelAsync();
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Application.ExecutablePath);
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
```

else if you are wanting your program to cancel the download task and start download again,

```
webClient.CancelAsync();
//Initializing A New One So It Can't Cause Any Issues
webClient = new WebClient();  
webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);  
webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);  
webClient.DownloadFileAsync("https://195.50.139.130:5001/FTP/KlingGastro Update/file.txt", "C:\\file.txt");
```

Hope It Helps! If It Doesn't Help, Please Let Us Know Exactly What You Are Trying To Achieve.